# Default Gmail account

Tags: google-account, google-multi-login

My daughter logged in to her Gmail account and it seems to be the default; when I open Gmail, hers is first choice, then mine; she lives in another state and only used her account here once.

How do I remove her account as an option every time I log in?

Answer (score 0):

When logging in, there's two buttons below the list of accounts, one saying Remove. Hit that and then click the little X next to her account.